# Global Styles with litelement

Tags: css, typescript, web-component, lit-element

I'm developing web components with lit-element (Typescript) and I want to create some css files to define a "global theme" for my web components package.

My structure in disk is this one:

src

┣ css

┃ ┣ color.css.ts

┃ ┗ size.css.ts

┣ button.css.ts

┣ WCButton.ts

┗ WcTheme.ts

Let me explain:

1. Css folder is to include separate files for declare defaults (in this example colors and size):

```
import { css } from "lit-element";

export const defaultColor = css`
    .primary{
        background: #356e3b;
    }
    .secondary{
        background: #5b8e48;
    }
    .terciary{
        background: #302e2b;
    }
`;
```

(color.css.ts code)

2. WcTheme.ts file is to integrate the files inside css folder into a single file:

```
import { defaultSize } from './css/size.css';
import { defaultColor } from './css/color.css';

import { LitElement } from 'lit-element';

export class WcTheme extends LitElement {
  static styles = [defaultColor, defaultSize];
}
```

3. button.css.ts are the CSS rules for a concrete component (in this case, for a button)

```
import { css } from "lit-element";

export const buttonStyles = css`
  .btn-default {
      border: 1px solid lime;
  }
```

4. WcButton.ts is the code definition of the web component (button)

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

import { WcTheme } from './WcTheme';
import { buttonStyles } from "./button.css";

export class WcButton extends LitElement {

  static get styles() {
    return [WcTheme.getStyles(),buttonStyles];
  }

  public render() {

    return html`
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-default"
      >
        <span class="primary h1">Test</span>
      </button>
    `;
  }
}
```

This structure throw the next error:

```
[tsc] src/WCButton.ts(6,14): error TS2417: Class static side 'typeof WcButton' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof LitElement'.
[tsc]   Types of property 'styles' are incompatible.
[tsc]     Type '(CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray | undefined'.
[tsc]       Type '(CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'CSSResultArray'.
[tsc]         The types returned by 'concat(...)' are incompatible between these types.
[tsc]           Type '(CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '(CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray)[]'.
[tsc]             Type 'CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray'.
[tsc]               Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CSSResult | CSSStyleSheet | CSSResultArray'.
[tsc]
[tsc] 22:12:09 - Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

because I can integrate CSSResultArray created by WcTheme.ts and CSSResult created in button.css.ts.

Could anyone help me to solve that or would be a better solution for do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with the same file structure, and in WcButton.ts I have changed:

```
static get styles() {
    return [WcTheme.getStyles(), buttonStyles]; }
```

to

```
static get styles() {
    return [...WcTheme.styles, buttonStyles]; }
```